# How to work out the years and left over days between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to work out the years and days between 2 dates. An example would be "How many years and remaining days has it been since World War 2?". I can work out the total days but i am struggling to make sure the remaining day count is correct. I am also not taking into account leap years as I don't know where to start with that.

http://jsfiddle.net/aw5rvpk0/16/

jQuery

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24);
}

var totalDayCount = Math.round((daydiff(parseDate($('#first').val()), parseDate($('#second').val()))));

var yearCount = Math.round((totalDayCount / 365) * 10) / 10;

var dayCountMinusYears = Math.round((totalDayCount - (yearCount * 365)));

$('.years').text(yearCount);
$('.days').text(dayCountMinusYears);
```

HTML

```
<input id="first" value="1/1/2000"/>
<input id="second" value="6/10/2005"/>

<div>Year Count <span class="years">0</span></div>
<div>Day Count Minus The Years Count <span class="days">0</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `.getTime()` , `String.prototype.split()` , `.toFixed()`

```js
var inputs = $("input");
var then = new Date(inputs.eq(0).val()).getTime();
var now = new Date(inputs.eq(1).val()).getTime();
var years = ((now - then) / 86400000 / 365).toFixed(2);
$(".years").text(years.split(".")[0]);
$(".days").text(365 * Number("." + years.split(".")[1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="first" value="1/1/2000"/>
<input id="second" value="6/10/2005"/>

<div>Year Count <span class="years">0</span></div>
<div>Day Count Minus The Years Count <span class="days">0</span></div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aw5rvpk0/17/

---

Edit, Updated

> That works but I am from the UK so i need to convert the date format
>   once it has been stored in the variable. Is that possible?

Try converting `input` to "dd/mm/yy" format utilizing `String.prototype.split()` , `Array.prototype.slice()` , `Array.prototype.reverse()` , `Array.prototype.join()` , `String.prototype.concat()`

```js
var inputs = $("input");
var then = inputs.eq(0).val();
then = new Date(then.split("/").slice(0,2).reverse()
                .join("/").concat("/" + then.slice(-4))).getTime();
var now = inputs.eq(1).val();
now = new Date(now.split("/").slice(0,2).reverse()
               .join("/").concat("/" + now.slice(-4))).getTime();
console.log(then, now)
var years = ((now - then) / 86400000 / 365).toFixed(5);
$(".years").text(years.split(".")[0]);
$(".days").text(365 * Number("." + years.split(".")[1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" value="30/01/2000"/>
<input id="second" value="31/01/2001"/>

<div>Year Count <span class="years">0</span></div>
<div>Day Count Minus The Years Count <span class="days">0</span></div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aw5rvpk0/36/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for 1 or 2 days but I can't see why

Comment: _"That doesn't seem to work for 1 or 2 days but I can't see why"_ Not certain interpret correctly ? What is "doesn't seem to work for 1 or 2 days" ? Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Sorry, here is an update jsfiddle which is looking for the years and days between 1 day http://jsfiddle.net/aw5rvpk0/32/

Comment: @2ne Try adjusting `input` value to "dd/mm/yy" format , substituting `.toFixed(5)` for `.toFixed(2)` http://jsfiddle.net/aw5rvpk0/34/

Comment: That works but I am from the UK so i need to convert the date format once it has been stored in the variable. Is that possible?